# HTML5 Fullscreen Image ASP.Net

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, html

Got a very simple question and I am overwhelmed with :( !

My requirement is that, ASP.Net is used server side to generate HTML5 document and sent to client side.
The HTML5 document contains a single Img element with src set on server side.

I want the browser to show the Image in full screen, once the page has been loaded.

Is that possible, if yes, how do I do it?

Came across some Fullscreen info here:
http://www.sitepoint.com/use-html5-full-screen-api/

Thanks!

Comment: Please show us *what have you tried so far*?

Comment: When you say full-screen, do you actually mean fullscreen? Or do you mean fill browser window with image